# Check and remove comma from csv file before splitting

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, streamreader

I am trying to read and upload on my database a certain csv file with certain data which the users selects. Lets say the data contains name, age and height. The problem is when the name contains a comma(,).

Example:

Mark, Smith   20     170

As the system will think that this is another field and will split. Below is the code I am using, I need to filter this comma and remove it before splitting into different columns.

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            var fileName = string.Format(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] value = line.Split(',');
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row;
            foreach (string dc in value)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc));
            }

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                Name cl = new Name();
                try
                {
                    cl.Name= value[0].Trim('"');
                    cl.Age= value[1].Trim('"');
                    cl.Height= value[2].Trim('"');

new Data().addPerson(cl);
}
```

Comment: For the sample data you have shown this will not be possible, because we have no way to distinguish commas inside values from commas used as column seperators. If the data values are additionally delimited, e.g. if they are surrounded by double quotes, it will be possible to filter for commas inside the values. `"Mark, Smith", "20", "170"`

Comment: I dont have access to my old code for a few hours, but you would need to wrap the name column in " tags and then look for a comman between the " tags and then do a string replace

Comment: in the csv would look something like "Mark, Fenech", "20", "170" and when spltting into columns the comma between name and surname would assume that this is the next column

Comment: You can make a Regex for the filtering, which only split if there is a quote " and a sign befor the comma

Comment: @SeeuD1 how please?

Comment: something like that: input.split("(".+?(?!"),)"), the regex is working but the splitting is without trying regex: (".+?(?!"),) if you want to try it, here is a good website: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick & dirty solution I cobbeled together. There might be a more elegant solution using regex. But hey, it works...

```
using System.Text;

var line = "\"Mark, Fenech\", \"20\", \"170\"";

public static string RemoveColumnDelimitersInsideValues(string input) {

    const char valueDelimiter = '"';
    const char columnDelimiter = ',';

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    bool isInsideValue = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
        var currentChar = input[i];

        if (currentChar == valueDelimiter) {
            isInsideValue = !isInsideValue;
            output.Append(currentChar);
            continue;
        }

        if (currentChar != columnDelimiter || !isInsideValue) {
            output.Append(currentChar);
        }
        // else ignore columnDelimiter inside value
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f2Wfde)

Comment: my string is not listed with "\" its is like this: "Mark, Fenech, 20, 170"

Comment: The `\ ` is just used to escape the `"` that seperate the values, this is needed if I want to write the string `"Mark, Fenech", "20", "170"` in C#. If you inspect the value of your `line` in the debugger, it will look just like this. As mentioned in my original comment, if the values are not delimited, it will not be possible to remove the commas inside them.